# Remote desktop to a host I only know the mac address of

Tags: networking, router

I want to use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a PC on my local network; I actually connect to a router which forwards to the PC.

Unfortunately I don't know the IP address of the router: my DHCP has no option to force IP addresses. I can look up the IP with eg `arp -a`, but I would like to have this automated (so my wife can use it...). Is this possible?

More info on setup:

- My pc: 192.168.123.5
- My router: 192.168.123.10 (for instance, but it changes) / 10.10.1.1
- PC I want to connect to : 10.10.1.2

I would like to have some alias that always points at the 192.168.123.x IP that my router gets.

Comment: does \\pcName not work?

Comment: No, I guess it doesn't see the pcName behind the router

Comment: ah, didn't realise you were jumping subnets - I've never used it in that way. I'd switch to TeamViewer for anything like that; far easier to work with, punches through router/firewalls with little user input & doesn't care where each machine is, or even if it moves.

Comment: I would set a fixed address for the router, which will make this more easy and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you're trying to come up with ways, however painful, to cope with problems caused by a misconfigured router.

Most people run into problems like this because they added a second router to their network to provide connectivity to devices in another part of the house, but they didn't configure the extra router correctly for that role. When putting in a second router like that, you need to configure it to simply be a transparent bridge between the existing LAN and the wireless clients. Unfortunately, a lot of folks don't know how to do this or don't take the time to find out, so they leave it set up as a full NAT gateway router as if it was at the head of the network. This setup causes your home network to be split into two separate LANs and makes it tricky for devices on one side of the extra router to reach devices on the other side of the extra router.

In 99.99% of home networks, the only correct place for a *NAT gateway* router is at the head of the network (integrated into the same box as the broadband modem, or as the only device connected to the LAN port of the "modem-only" broadband modem). On any other routers you add to your network, you should disable NAT service and DHCP service. If you secondary router doesn't give you an option to disable these features, you can set the DHCP IP address lease pool to zero length, and then be sure to connect a LAN port (not the WAN port) of the secondary router to a LAN port of the primary router.

If it turns out that you're one of the 0.001% that has a truly good reason to be doing double-NAT (running a NAT gateway service on more than one router on your network), then this won't be the right Answer for you. But I still wanted to post this Answer for the 99.99% of people that might find this page when their real problem is that they shouldn't be running double NAT.